# Liferay: How to change the textarea for ckeditor in the portal's own pages?

Tags: module, ckeditor, fragment, liferay, hook

I need the CKEditor field to appear by default in the portal property pages instead of the textarea fields.

For example, in the Categories page when you create a Category there are 2 fields (name and description), so the description field should be a CKEditor instead of textarea.

I have tried to add these lines in the portal-ext.properties file but without results:

```
editor.wysiwyg.default=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-impl.portlet.ddm.text_html.ftl=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-impl.portlet.ddm.text_html.textarea=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.blogs.edit_entry.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.journal.edit_article_content.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.announcements.edit_entry.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.mail.edit.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.mail.edit_message.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.taglib.ui.discussion.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.taglib.ui.email_notification_settings.jsp=ckeditor
```

If it were a default widget I could make a hook/fragment but we are talking about an element of a page of the portal, do you think it is possible?

Comment: 1. this is not programming related, please see [help/on-topic]. 2. the description field is not meant to hold HTML text, but just plain text - if you change that, the HTML won't be rendered properly in other places where it's used by default. 3. CKEditor changed over time (in version, usage etc), so if you ask this question in a place where it's on-topic, remember to also state the version number that you're targeting. However, I'd recommend to rather solve the underlying problem in a different way. I'm assuming this is an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364505)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's true that I have not well formulated the question, it's a difficult issue to raise. I will take into account the version for the next time (it was Liferay 7.3). I'll check the help center for an alternative solution